# @isUnique not working in GraphQL SDL( aws appsync)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-appsync

Iam new to graphql.Iam implementing a react-native app using aws appsync.We are facing problem in implementing @isUnique and giving it is giving me an error

```
Failed to parse schema document - ensure it's a valid SDL-formatted document.
type Person {
id: ID! @isUnique
createdAt: String!
updateAt: String!
name: String!
messages: [Messages!]!
    @relation(name: "UserMessages")}
```

I want to have a random id generated for each user in the schema.How can we achieve this. 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: isn't it @unique?

Comment: @unique is also not working i have tried it Elkhan Mamedov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@isUnique` is a provider-specific directive. If you want to generate unique identifiers on the server with AWS AppSync, you can use `$util.autoId()` in the resolver. The [AWS AppSync - Up and Running](https://hackernoon.com/aws-appsync-up-and-running-560a42d96ba7) blog post has details.

Comment: Thanks!! that was help full.@Rohan Deshpande

Answer (score 0):

First, it's @unique if you're using appolo-server and @isUnique if graphcool. Second, ids will be unique by default there is no need for @unique. It's for other fields like email or username.

Take a look here [Schema directives - Appolo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives.html)
If you're using Graphcool [this](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/database/data-modelling-eiroozae8u/#graphql-directives)